# How to move comma seperated ids from one row to another row?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database table like this

`Id          user_id         folder       product_ids`

```
1            4              test1        2,3,4
2            4              test2        7,8,9
3            4              test3        10,11,12
```

Here I have saved product ids comma separated.Users have created their folders like this and wanted to move one or more products to another folder. Let say if user want he can select product id(8) and move it from test2 to test3 and the result set will look like this:

`Id          user_id         folder       product_ids`

```
1            4              test1        2,3,4
2            4              test2        7,9
3            4              test3        10,11,12,8
```

How can I do it with sql and php?

Comment: Don't store data like that, it will only cause you problems. (As you may have noticed by now...)

Comment: Just share your code if you wrote anything ?

Comment: SQL has this great way of storing lists of things.  It is called a "table" not a "string".  You should restructure your data so you have a junction table between users and products.

Comment: @Gordon Can you tell me how can I structure the data? So that I will get the results what I have wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **MySQL** doesn't have a built-in **REPLACE** by **REGEX** :(
**NOTE** : 
Please, update **PRODUCT_TABLE** by your Table Name

Here is a solution :

```
 <?
    /**
      * @param String $folderSrc
      * @param String $folderDst
      * @param String $movedProductIds
      * @param String $userId
      * @return String Built SQL Query
      */
    function buildSqlQueryMoveProductId ($folderSrc, $folderDst, $movedProductIds, $userId) {
    return 
        "UPDATE PRODUCT_TABLE 
         SET PRODUCT_IDS = 
            CASE
                WHEN FOLDER = '" . $folderSrc . "' THEN (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (PRODUCT_IDS, '," . $movedProductIds . "', ''), '" . $movedProductIds . ",', ''), '" . $movedProductIds . "', ''))
                WHEN FOLDER = '" . $folderDst . "' THEN (CONCAT (IF (LENGTH(PRODUCT_IDS) > 0, CONCAT (PRODUCT_IDS, ','), '' ), '" . $movedProductIds . "'))
                ELSE PRODUCT_IDS
            END
        WHERE USER_ID = " . $userId;
    }
    // Example
    print moveProductId ('test1', 'test2', '3', 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not to store comma separated values in one column.
MySQL can perfectly handle large tables, so you could enter each product ID as a separate row.

You could also create multiple tables, say one holds the folder data.
Then another table could hold the primary keys of the folder table, along with the product IDs, and the user ID.

The more you store in a single table, the less organised it becomes.
I am not sure what's best performance-wise, but organisation is key, especially later on.

EDIT:

So let's say you create a table like this:

```
ID  User_ID  Folder Product_ID

1   4        test1  2
2   4        test2  7
3   4        test3  10
```

You could now simply look for the Product_ID, and UPDATE the folder name.
So when you pass the Product ID on to the update script, you could use a query somewhat like this:

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET Folder = :folder WHERE Product_ID = :pid
```

Then bind the folder name and product ID.
Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) about PDO if you're unfamiliar with prepared statements.
I would recommend binding the values, as you're talking about user input, which can always be manipulated, causing a possible security breach.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/*Fetch your product ids and you will return sting of ids like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
 * 
 */


// product Ids. From where you want to remove id
$productOne="1,2,3,4,5";

// product Ids, From where you want to put id
$productTwo="6,7,8,9";

//product 1 array
$productOneArray=explode(",",$productOne);

//product 2 array
$productTwoArray=explode(",",$productTwo);

//Id which you want to change
$movingId = "5";

//Let's remove your product.
foreach ($productOneArray as $key=>$id){
    if($id == $movingId){
        unset($productOneArray[$key]);
    }
}//BINGO !! you remove your id


//Add it to another product ids
array_push($productTwoArray,$movingId);
//Bingo You did it


//now turn both into string
$productOne=implode(",",$productOneArray);
$productTwo=implode(",",$productTwoArray);

//Update both the values in database

?>
```

If you need more help in hindi or gujrati, you can ask me.

If you want to move multiple ids

```
<?php
$name="parag";
if($name=="parag"){
    echo uniqid().$name;
}
?>

<script>
    $("div").css("width", "100px");
    $("div").css("height", "100px");
</script>
<?php
echo "<pre>";
/*Fetch your product ids and you will return sting of ids like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
 * 
 */


// product Ids. From where you want to remove id
$productOne="1,2,3,4,5";

// product Ids, From where you want to put id
$productTwo="6,7,8,9";

//product 1 array
$productOneArray=explode(",",$productOne);

//product 2 array
$productTwoArray=explode(",",$productTwo);

//Id which you want to change
$movingId = "2,3,4";
$movingIdArray = explode(",", $movingId);

//Let's remove your product.
foreach($movingIdArray as $movingIds){
    foreach ($productOneArray as $key=>$id){
        if($id == $movingIds){
            unset($productOneArray[$key]);
        }
    }//BINGO !! you remove your id
}
print_r($productOneArray);



//Add it to another product ids
array_push($productTwoArray,$movingId);
//Bingo You did it


//now turn both into string
$productOne=implode(",",$productOneArray);
$productTwo=implode(",",$productTwoArray);

//Update both the values in database

echo "productOne = ".$productOne."<br />";
echo "productTwo = ".$productTwo."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Let say I want move 2,3,4 to $producttwo.How I can achieve it?

Comment: see.. in the edited answer... there is working example of multiple ids....
paste this code in your php file and check.
...
if it is helpful, accept my answer and vote me up

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use json_encode() while adding product_ids.
When you insert product id just encode it and save. & while moving from folder read that json and decode it. 
Add or remove respective ids from json then again save to database

Comment: @ Mangesh Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You got answers on how to achieve this with php-code. But you really should normalize your database. A normalized database only contains tables where each table holds data describing a certain entity and relates to other entities through foreign-keys. You already did this by connecting your user-data through the foreign key "user_id", now move on and refactor your table to the other entities "folder" and "product".

Your final schema may look like this:

**Table users**

```
user_id
user_name
etc.
```

**Table folders**

```
folder_id
folder_name
user_id
etc.
```

**Table products**

```
product_id
folder_id
product_name
etc.
```

With this, to move a product from one folder to another, just change the folder_id of a record from products-table.
To fetch all products from one folder you use joins:

```
SELECT folders.*, products.* from products
JOIN folders on folders.folder_id = products.folder_id
WHERE folders.folder_id = your_desired_folder_id
```

Read more on database-normalization with lots of examples and reasons why to do this (despite the problems you are already facing) here:
http://www.dbnormalization.com/

Regards,
jojo