# Filter comma separated values from same table

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Comma separated values not in id column]

Can anybody help me to get the sub_cat(csv) values which are not in id column from same table.

(sub_cat) comma separated values are the ids of same table, i need to get the values which are not in id column. Like 2,3,7 are present in id column whereas 20,24 are not. I need to get 20,24 only.

Comment: can you please elaborate??

Comment: I don't think anyone can understand your question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, (sub_cat) comma separated values are the ids of same table, i need to get the values which are not in id column. Like 2,3,7 are present in id column whereas 20,24 are not. I need to get 20,24 only. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Bad database design is bad ... create a `sub_cat` table and (possibly, depending on the relationships) a `sub_cat_to_category` table and do it properly - you'll save yourself a lot of headaches in the long run. Or if the sub-category is a category id; use something like parent id, join the table to itself... just don't store CSV data in a record like this.

Comment: CD001@ Yes, i know this is not the best way, but if you can help me to get the desired result that would be great.

Comment: The (updated) answer from Matthijs Perik looks about right to me... assuming you're on at least MySQL 5 (i.e. nested queries are supported) - though it does kinda sidestep the CSV bit...

Comment: @CD001 Its will not work as the values are comma seperated, i have also tryed it.

Comment: Do you need a pure SQL answer (which would probably require defining a function)? or, since you've got PHP tagged in the post, you could pretty easily create a PHP loop.

Comment: @CD001 It would be great through query else i need to hit the DB again and again as comma separated values increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this purely in MySQL required writing a stored procedure; you'll need to change the database name `test` to the actual name of your database. It would have been a whole lot easier to do it with PHP - but where's the fun in that?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test.check_subcats(
    IN s_delimiter VARCHAR(30)
    )

    DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA

    BEGIN
        DECLARE s_csv TEXT;
        DECLARE i_subcat_index INT(10) unsigned DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE i_subcat_count INT(10) unsigned;
        DECLARE l_category_done INT(10) DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE c_category CURSOR FOR SELECT category.sub_cat FROM category;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET l_category_done = TRUE;

        -- create a temporary table to hold every csv value
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_csv( cvalue VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL );

        OPEN c_category;
        l_category: LOOP
            FETCH c_category INTO s_csv;

            IF l_category_done THEN
                LEAVE l_category;
            ELSE
                -- determine the number of sub-categories
                SELECT (LENGTH(s_csv) - LENGTH(REPLACE(s_csv, s_delimiter, ''))) + 1 INTO i_subcat_count;

                -- loop to store all csv values
                WHILE i_subcat_index <= i_subcat_count DO 
                    INSERT INTO tmp_csv ( cvalue ) (
                    SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
                            SUBSTRING_INDEX(s_csv, s_delimiter, i_subcat_index),
                            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s_csv, s_delimiter, i_subcat_index - 1)) + 1
                        ), s_delimiter, '')
                    );

                    SET i_subcat_index = i_subcat_index + 1;
                END WHILE;
            END IF;

            SET i_subcat_index = 1;
        END LOOP;       
        CLOSE c_category;

        SELECT DISTINCT tmp_csv.cvalue FROM tmp_csv WHERE tmp_csv.cvalue NOT IN ( SELECT category.id FROM category );
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_csv;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm not 100% certain as to how robust it is but it was working with your data on my dev box.

You specify the delimiter for your CSV data when you call the procedure thus:

```
CALL `check_subcats`(',');
```

Essentially this loops through the `category` table to read `sub_cat`. It then splits the `sub_cat` value into chunks using the delimiter provided (much like PHPs `explode()` function) and writes every one of those values to a temporary table.

This then gives you a temporary table holding all your CSV data in individual bits and it's then a simple matter of selecting everything from that data that's `NOT IN` the `category.id` list.

Comment: It was a little too involved for me to get done in my lunch break at work - hence the delay in the response, I had to wait until I got home ;)

Comment: I have not been using stored procedures yet, but i'll give it a try. New things are always interesting.

Answer (score 2):

As I have elaborated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740776/how-to-move-comma-seperated-ids-from-one-row-to-another-row/28741298#28741298) post, I recommend not storing data in CSV format.
This gives trouble accessing and updating it.

I am not sure about this, but you might be able to simply use:

```
SELECT sub_cat FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT sub_cat FROM table_name
)
```

However, I always prefer to store only one ID per row.

Comment: No, this will get other ids from table.